# glTexImage2D reads beyond bounds of buffer (iOS)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, buffer-overflow

In the following simple code, I load a 1-channel data to a texture. I use `glTexImage2D()` with `GL_LUMINANCE` (which is a 1-channel format) and `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, so it should take one byte per pixel. I allocate a buffer with size equal the number of pixels (2 x 2) which represents the input pixel data (the values of the pixels don't matter for our purposes).

When you run the following code with Address Sanitizer enabled, it detects a heap buffer overflow in the call to `glTexImage2D()`, saying that it tried to read beyond the bounds of the heap-allocated buffer:

```
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>

//...

EAGLContext* context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

GLsizei width = 2, height = 2;
void *data = malloc(width * height); // contents don't matter for now
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
             0,
             GL_LUMINANCE,
             width,
             height,
             0,
             GL_LUMINANCE,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             data);
```

This is 100% reproducible and happens on both iOS simulator and device. Only if you increase the size of the buffer to 6 will it not overflow (2 bigger than the expected size of 4).

Sizes of 1x1 and 4x4 don't seem to have this problem, but 2x2 and 3x3 do. It seems kind of arbitrary.

What is wrong?

Comment: Is `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` set to `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it thanks to @genpfault's comment.

I need to set the unpack alignment to 1:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

Specifically, the unpack alignment determines the alignment for the start of each row. The default value is 4. Since my rows don't have any special alignment, and there are no gaps between row bytes, the alignment should be 1.

The first row will always be aligned because `malloc` allocates 16-aligned buffers. But the second and subsequent rows were misaligned with the default alignment of 4 unless the row length was a multiple of 4 (this explains why 2x2 and 3x3 don't work, but 4x4 does). 1x1 happens to work because it has no second row.